# Not able to convert SecretKey to bytearray ( java)

Tags: java, android, keystore, secret-key

I'm trying to get the byte array value of the genrated SecretKey, but the result is always null,

This is my code :

```
mKeyStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PROVIDER);
            mKeyStore.load(null);
            KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = null;
            if (!mKeyStore.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS_AES)) {
                KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
                        KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PROVIDER);

                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder = null;
                builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                        KEY_ALIAS_AES,
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT);
                builder.setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                        .setKeySize(256);
                keyGenerator.init(builder.build());
                sKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
                secretKeyEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(sKey);
                mKeyStore.setKeyEntry(KEY_ALIAS_AES, secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey().getEncoded(), null);
            }
            try {
                tmpKey = mKeyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS_AES, null).getEncoded();
            } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

tmpKey is always null, any help please ?

Comment: You've thrown away the result of `generateKey()`, and you haven't added the key to the keystore, so when you try to get it out you fail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
sKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
                secretKeyEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(sKey);
                mKeyStore.setKeyEntry(KEY_ALIAS_AES, secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey().getEncoded(), null);
            }
            try {
                tmpKey = mKeyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS_AES, null).getEncoded();
            }

result is always null

Comment: I can't read that. Nobody can. Don't post code in comments. Edit it into your question.

Comment: I already did it

Comment: What is null? The result of `getEncoded()`? Why are you storing the encoding of the key and then trying to get the encoding of the encoding? Why are you wanting to recover the key as a byte array instead of a `Key` object?

Comment: I'm using a custom algorithm written in C / ndk, this algorithm accept key as a byte array, so i need to convert the generated key to byte array each time i need to use this algorithm but the result is null. If you have any idea how to store a random value (byte arraye) in key store or any secure zone in android, that will be very helpful. thank you

Comment: For your information, this is my first time working with keystore, following the examples in internet and android official documentations, still cannot figure out where is the problem

Comment: i did what i need in other way.

1- Generate random value ( key (byte array) )
2 - Encrypt the key and store it in sharedpreferences.
3 - Decrypt the stored value when i need it to get the key.

it works and it fill my need, thank you for your help

Comment: You didntt find any examples where you stored the key encoding and then tried to get the encoding of the encoding. The idea is to learn by your mistakes, not jsut find a completely different solution. All you needed to know was right there in what I wrote.

Comment: AndroidKeystore keys are non-extractable. You can use them but you can not get the content.